# Can someone help with the nomenclature of this metal complex. MarvinSketch is giving me trouble

Tags: nomenclature, coordination-compounds, organometallic-compounds

I’m trying to get a name for the structure above using MarvinSketch for my undergraduate senior thesis. This is the first time I’ve had to draw a metal complex in MarvinSketch, and I’m having trouble getting the program to name it as is.

Right now, using the “structure to name” feature, the name I’m getting is 8,14‐dimethyl‐2-λ-4,20-λ-4,21-λ-4,27-λ-4‐tetraaza‐1-cobaltaheptacyclo[12.6.6.11,9.02,7.015,20.021,26.013,27]-heptacosa2(7),3,5,9(27),10,12,15(20),16,18,21(26),22,24‐dodecaene‐1,1‐diol, and I’m pretty darn sure that’s wrong.

I think this issue is that I drew the water molecules as being attached to the carbon via coordinate bonds but the polypyridine ligand as being attached by normal single bonds. I did this because the program wouldn’t even give a name if all bonds were drawn as coordinate bonds, and if I try to show the water molecules being attached by normal bonds, the program always either gives the waters a formal charge or removes one of the hydrogens to make it an -OH bonded to the cobalt.

I was wondering if someone could help me figure out how to get the program to properly name this complex, and perhaps also help me get the program to stop adding a formal charge/removing one of the hydrogens from the waters if I change the bond type to not be coordinate.

This is not a very important part of my thesis so if there’s no relatively easy way to get the IUPAC name I’m not going to worry about it (though it would be nice). I also unfortunately don’t have access to books on nomenclature from my school with us being remote.

Thank you very much[image: cobalt complex]

Comment: You should just name the ligand and then it's a small step to whole complex that program won't make, but you should be able to do easily.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response! So if I just name the ligand in MarvinSketch, I get the name: 2‐[1,1‐bis(pyridin‐2‐yl)ethyl]‐6‐[1‐(pyridin‐2‐yl)ethyl]pyridine. Now that I have that, how would I go about naming the metal complex? I've not taken inorganic yet* and I've never learned IUPAC nomenclature for metal complexes.                                 
                                                                                                                                 *The class is only offered in the spring and unfortunately, I've had to wait for senior year spring to take it.

Comment: As I said this is the easy part. You can check for example [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordination_complex#Nomenclature_of_coordination_complexes) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the link! Would the name therefore be: diaqua(2‐[1,1‐bis(pyridin‐2‐yl)ethyl]‐6‐[1‐(pyridin‐2‐yl)ethyl]pyridine)cobalt(III)?

Comment: Well, there's probably need for curly bracket, but more importantly, is this Co(II) or (III) 'cause (II) is more probable.

Comment: In my lab notebook, it is Co(III). We used hydrogen peroxide to oxidize the Co(II) to Co(III) because we wanted it to be NMR active. By curly brackets, do you mean it would be diaqua{2‐[1,1‐bis(pyridin‐2‐yl)ethyl]‐6‐[1‐(pyridin‐2‐yl)ethyl]pyridine}cobalt(III)? Is this the full name of the complex? Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115278/discussion-between-planejerle18-and-mithoron).